# Custom live tile windows phone 7.8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, live-tile

I want to create a custom live tile. I just need to display a number with large digits (1 to 4 digits) in the center of the tile, no icon, no text or anything else and it should be possible to update the tile also.
I have tried the default tile, but it displays the number at the up-right corner with small font and cannot pass number 99.Any ideas? (programming in Visual Basic)

Comment: https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a guide, how to render your own tiles even with transparency, but beware of the memory consumption in background agent. Typically you should render at max only one tile:
**Pro Live Tiles for Windows Phone**
http://suchan.cz/?p=110